# Babel breaks maketitle on moderncv's casual and banking templates

Tags: titles, babel, moderncv

I'm working on my CV and I started using the `classic` theme. After finishing the document, I trried to switch to the `casual` theme (also happens in the  `banking` theme), but I get the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \global 
l.58 \end{document}
```

After searching for a solution for some time, I commented out all the optional fields and it worked, so I kept on uncommenting fields and, when I get to the 3rd or 4th, it threw the error again. If I comment one of the first and uncomment one of the last ones, it also works, so its not a problem with the fields. After that, I tried to remove `babel` from the document and all the fields worked again.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}


\moderncvtheme[green]{casual} %banking also breaks but classic and olstyle dont

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}

% personal data
\firstname{Juan Antonio}
\familyname{\\Orozco Bianchi}
\title{Tecnologo en informatica y computacion}
\address{Calzada Central  1243}{Zapopan,Jalisco}
\mobile{+52 (33) 17186920}
\phone{+52 (33) 31651436}
\email{iam@mexcoder.com}
\homepage{http://mexcoder.com}

\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{Foto}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%resumee contend

\end{document}
```

and the log is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwrm343floaqths/cv_casual.error.log).

Is there any way to make `babel` and the `casual` theme play nice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with `~`; add the `es-notilde` option to `babel`:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman,es-notilde]{babel}
```

and use either `\~n` for the eñe or `ñ` in the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: It solves the problem, but can you explain why?

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco `moderncv` uses `~` in some places where it probably shouldn't. Anyway, using `~` as a shorthand prefix is not recommended either.