# Why the language selection of babel affects the page number format?

Tags: page-numbering, babel, front-matter, roman-numerals, spanish

I writing a report in spanish, and I would like the page numbers in the `\frontmatter` to be numbered with lowercase roman numbers. However, the selection of spanish in the babel package changes the configuration to something else (not sure if uppercase or small caps, but I think is the later).

Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\renewcommand\thepage{\lowercase{\roman{page}}}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\mainmatter
\chapter{More stuff}
Ut sapien nisl, rutrum eget laoreet blandit, eleifend eu sapien. Cursus non.

\end{document}
```

That code gives the desired result. But changing the 2nd line to `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` puts the page numbers in the frontmatter in a different format. How can I change them back to lowercase roman numbers?

Other questions in this forum deals with inconsistencies between the `\tableofcontents` and the actual format presented in the document, but I couldn't find the answer to this particular issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}` should do. Remove `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\lowercase{\roman{page}}}`

Comment: Yes, you're right. My question is duplicate. You guys have amazing search skills. I search for an answer for a significant amount of time and the decided to post the question. Sorry for the duplicate. Should I eliminate my question then?

Comment: I remembered the existence of an option because I solved a [problem related to it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159868/). So I looked in `texdoc spanish` and searched for `roman` in the PDF file; there I found the option's name and I could look for questions with it in the site. `;-)`. Don't worry! The question will point to the duplicate; the problems are slightly different, so it can help future readers having two questions about it (but only one with answers).